# Python solve_bvp fourth order differential equation

Tags: python, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I'm trying to apply scipy's `solve_bvp` to the following problem

`T''''(z) = -k^4 * T(z)`

With boundary conditions on a domain of size `l` and some constant `A`:

`T(0) = T''(0) = T'''(l) = 0`

`T'(l) = A`

So far, I've reduced the fourth order equation to a 1st order system and written the following function:

```py
def fun1(t, y):
    y0 = y[1]
    y1 = y[2]
    y2 = y[3]
    y3 = -k**4 * y0
    ret = np.vstack((y0, y1, y2, y3))
    return ret
```

Then, I've established my boundary conditions, trying to follow the documentation (which I don't really understand...)

```py
def bc(ua, ub):
    # 0th, 1st, 2nd and 3rd derivative BCs
    return [ua[0], ub[1]-A, ua[2], ub[3]]
```

Then I set up my initial guesses

```py
A, l = 10, 3
x_init = [0, l]
y_init = [[0, 0], [0, A], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

when I run `solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y)`, however, I get the wrong solution. I don't know quite why. The solver converges, but it doesn't look like how I expect it to.

Can someone please explain what the `bc` function is supposed to return for Von Neumann boundary conditions? I'm really struggling to wrap my head around the documentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In computing `y3`, you need to actually use `y[0]`, not `y0=y[1]`.

To avoid such misunderstanding I would write

```
def fun1(t, y):
    dy0 = y[1]
    dy1 = y[2]
    dy2 = y[3]
    dy3 = -k**4 * y[0]
    return np.vstack((dy0, dy1, dy2, dy3))
```